# MySQL data sync between Online and localhost databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have localhost(master) mysql database and need to get sync with online (slave) database; ex:www.abc.com

- currently im using manual data transferring by excel files. but this way is difficult to maintain.

any suggestion please.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can setup master slave replication. It copied automatically from a master to a slave database. Below link will be helpful to you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You could use following steps, everytime you need to Sync Slave with Master. Your problem seems to be more related to data move on adhoc basis.

1. Do export full database from Master.

   ```
   mysqldump -u root-proot dbname > db_export.sql
   ```
2. Import the step-1 exported data into Slave.

   ```
   mysql -uUsername -pPassword dbname < db_export.sql
   ```
3. Perform any environment settings if needed by systematic update/delete/insert.

Comment: thanks, worked on localhost  and how to import to online database, like www.xxxxxxxx.com

Comment: Use option -h to specify the host url of your master database like  `mysql -uUsername -pPassword dbname -h 'www.xxxxxxxxxx.com'< db_export.sql`

Comment: @Tharinduucsc does it work for you? If not, I could reattempt the answer.

Comment: didnt worked for me. can you check following output after running your code

http://textuploader.com/dfye9

Comment: @Tharinduucsc, problem is that your mysql command itself in not executing properly. Make sure, you are not using windows powershell. Also, run `mysql -u root -p -h 'www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com test -e "SHOW TABLES;" > abcd.txt` . This will prompt for password, If you see all the table names in your `abcd.txt`, then your command is good. Now, you could see `mysql -u root -p -h localhost test < d:\db_export.sql ' . I did check all my steps, and it works. SO believe it should work for you as well.